# How to detect when an element no longer has a shadow root without polling?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there a way to detect when a shadow root is removed from an element without polling? I would like to know if it is possible to do this in both v0 and v1 APIs. When in v1 API, it should work even if the root is closed.

Comment: Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I know I can (for example) poll using `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` to read the `shadowRoot` property, but that is ugly, and in v1 it only works with "open" shadow roots.

Comment: Can you include links to both specifications at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 Here's the differences: http://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (correct me if wrong), once an element has a shadow root, it will *always* have a shadow root. So, therefore this question is invalid because an element that has a shadow root must continue always having a shadow root.

Comment: What do you mean? An `html` element can have a `.shadowRoot` property that is set to `null`. How would this reflect whether the `ShadowDOM` of the element was previously populated with a document fragment?

Comment: Note also the `(user-agent)` `#shadow-root` attached to `DOM` elements, for example `<textarea>` or `<input>` where the `.shadowRoot` property is set to `null`. Are you trying to check for `.shadowRoot` on `user-agent` `ShadowDOM` as well?

Comment: @Supersharp Not certain how that would be related to Question? Are you interpreting Question as whether element has a `.shadowRoot` that is not `null`, or whether the element has or has had a `ShadowDOM`?

Comment: I'm interpreting the question In the light of this answer.

Comment: @Supersharp No worries.

Comment: @guest271314 sorry i thought you meant that one can *reset* the property to null but now i realize that you were certainly speaking of *initial* state of closed/UA Shadow Dom ;-)

Comment: @Supersharp Not certain what requirements of Question are? The `.shadowRoot` property of an element can have a `null` value, though the element can still have a `user-agent` `#shadow-dom`. Is Question if element has a `user-agent` `ShadowDOM`; a `ShadowDOM` created by user?

Comment: @guest271314 I think the requirements are about the open and closed Shadow Dom only, but I'm afraid it's impossible for closed ones (by definition)

Comment: @guest271314 If an element has a non-user-agent shadow root, if the root is "closed" (created with `el.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'})`) then `el.shadowRoot` will still be `null` (this is the new ShadowDOM v1). I how to detect when a shadow root is removed from an element, but know it was not even possible to remove a shadow root.

Answer (score 0):

The Shadow DOM can't be detached or replaced but its content can be removed.

You can set a `MutationObserver` on its `shadowRoot` to detect that:

```
var target= element.shadowRoot
var observer = new MutationObserver( callback )
observer.observe( target, { subtree: true, childList: true } )
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"The Shadow DOM can't be detached or be replaced"_? Content of `ShadowDOM` can be replaced.

Comment: @guest271314 content can be replaced but Shadow Dom itself no (as trusktr stated)